# Generate a very accurate mask showing where rivers and streams are using a DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, hydrology, hydrology-toolset

I would like to create a mask layer to show what the specific widths of a river or stream would be with certain variables. I'm using a high quality 1mx1m resolution DEM. I am able to do some things following tutorials to go in that direction by creating flow accumulation layers and what not. I’m not experienced enough to know the process to get the end product I need. Maybe this is called a flood map?

Note: This does not have to be real world accurate, but I would like for it to be precise in the calculation for my specific map.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely know that generating a flood map requires software like HecRas and someone with hydrology skills and training.  Still, it is not uncommon for people to generate detrended surface models, and then fuss with the color ramps to simulate flooding.  These detrending tools are generally troublesome but if you want to have a [go here are some instruction for detrending using QGIS](https://dancoecarto.com/creating-rems-in-qgis-the-idw-method) using a transect method.  [Here is an ArcGIS toolset](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Detrend-Surface-Models) with several other methods for detrending.

Comment: It looks like the link for the QGIS approach is missing.

Comment: Link added, sorry for that.